# Como preencher uma ontologia a partir do Java?

Tags: java, owl, ontologia

Estou trabalhando com ontologias, e possuo um arquivo OWL em que minha ontologia já está toda definida, classes, object properties, entre outros. Eu utilizo o Protegé 4.1 para preencher essas políticas, criando as instâncias de cada classe. Mas estou querendo criar essas instâncias diretamente pelo código java, utilizando a OWL API, porém não consegui achar nem na documentação como fazer isso. Então o que eu quero é basicamente pegar a ontologia criada mas sem instâncias, e criar essas instâncias no próprio código. Alguém já fez isso, ou sabe como fazer?

Comment: Durante minha dissertação de mestrado eu usei o jena, que na época era da hp. Isso foi em 2012. Eu sei que o jena foi doado para a apache. De uma olhada no [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org). A API pra manipular ontologias continua semelhante quando era da hp. Veja exemplos [aqui](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html). Espero que ajude.

Comment: Veja na Wiki se existe algum plugin
http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege_Ontology_Library

Answer (score -2):

Claro que eu sei como fazer isso! Mas antes, deixe-me contar uma história:

Era uma vez um desenvolvedor Java que precisava criar instâncias em sua ontologia OWL. Ele pesquisou e pesquisou, mas não encontrou nada de útil na documentação. Ele então decidiu pedir ajuda no StackOverflow, mas ninguém sabia como fazer. Desesperado, ele resolveu invocar um antigo e poderoso feitiço de programação. Ele escreveu o seguinte código:

```
OWLClass minhaClasse = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("http://minhaontologia.com#MinhaClasse"));
OWLIndividual minhaInstancia = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://minhaontologia.com#MinhaInstancia"));
OWLClassAssertionAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(minhaClasse, minhaInstancia);
manager.addAxiom(ontologia, axiom);
```

E para sua surpresa, funcionou! Ele ficou tão feliz que resolveu compartilhar sua descoberta com o mundo. E assim, todos os desenvolvedores Java que precisavam criar instâncias em suas ontologias OWL puderam viver felizes para sempre.

Moral da história: nunca subestime o poder de um bom feitiço de programação. E se precisar criar instâncias em sua ontologia OWL pelo código Java, use o código acima e seja feliz!

Comment: Salve, Jamal. A ideia do SO é ser um site de perguntas e respostas, de forma objetiva. A história que você criou, apesar de ser uma apresentação legal, não é muito condizente com a linha do SO (como você pode ver pelos votos negativos que recebeu -- e não, eu não votei negativo, foram outras pessoas). Se possível, edite sua resposta e a deixe objetiva. Abraço!